# How to Not Mock in JUnit

Tags: spring, junit4

We have a class in our code base called `LocationService` that basically does two things: makes HTTP calls to look up "Locations", and does a lot of work to map the information coming back into a usable format. For various reasons, primarily SRP, we would like to separate this class into two classes: `LocationLookupService` and `LocationFactoryService`. We've done that, and now the `LocationLookupService` will do its HTTP work and then call the Factory service. From a `src/main` perspective, this seems to work fine. However, the unit tests for the Lookup service are failing because the Factory isn't mocked - and I don't want it to be. I want the Lookup service to call the actual Factory without having to constantly rely on `doCallRealMethod` type mocks (which are dis-recommended).

How can I correctly wire the actual Factory service bean into the Lookup bean at test time? I have tried various combinations of @Autowired, calling the constructor, and so on.

```
@Autowired private LocationFactoryService locationFactoryService;

@InjectMocks private LocationLookupServiceImpl locationService;
```

Answer (score 0):

After speaking with a few more people, I think I've found the answer: using Spy functionality either through @Spy annotation or Mockito.spy() method. However, I've also been warned that this is a potential slippery slope to bad test code.